# How to install and use browser in headless mode from Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, skype

I'm hoping to Skype from my Pi Zero (Raspbian Jessie) and Raspberry Pi camera using the web client, web.skype.com. For this, I need to install a browser and start a Skype call that I send my video stream to.

1. What browser should I install for this purpose? I am having trouble getting Chromium set up. I tried this set of instructions: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=157049
2. How do I use web.skype.com to start a skype call and send a video/audio stream if I'm in headless display and can only use the command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [web api](https://dev.office.com/Skype/sdks#skypeWebSDK) in a headless environment to connect to Skype, in this case you can use, for example, a language like NodeJS.
You should take a look at open project like [this](https://github.com/vslinko/skype-api).
[This](https://github.com/ShyykoSerhiy/skyweb) is a project like the one you wan't to create. Starting from the Skype web it connect from command line.